# BeautifulSoup: Getting text inside <small> tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm doing some scraping exercises, and I'm scraping quotes.toshare.com.

I selected the div with all the quotes and successfully scraped all the quotes. Now I want to scrape the author name, and I'm stuck with the text inside a `<small></small>` tag which is inside a `<span>` with no class or any attribute:

```
<div class="quote" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
   <span class="text" itemprop="text">“The world as we have created it is a process of our 
   thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”
   </span>
   <span>by 
     **<small class="author" itemprop="author">Albert Einstein</small>**
     <a href="/author/Albert-Einstein">(about)</a>
   </span>
```

How can get that text??

`print(soup.find('small', class_ = 'author').text)` returns the correct output.

I have a loop to get all quotes and authors:

```
authors = []
quotes = []

for i in quote_text:
   quote = i.text.strip().split('\n')[0]
   author = i.find('small', class_ = 'author').text

   quotes.append(quote)
   authors.append(author)
```

but within the for-loop, the `author` variable is not populated as it should and I end up with a empty `authors` list.

What can I do to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is `quote_text` defined? Include a [example].

Comment: quote_text is the variable holding all the quotes text with the find_all method

Answer (score 0):

#### What happens?

At first - You should improve your question, as commented. While `qoute_text` is holding only the texts from the qoutes, you wont find the author.

#### How to fix?

Select not only the texts select the whole quote container:

```
soup.select('div.quote')
```

#### Solution (with some improvment)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_text = '''
<div class="quote" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/CreativeWork">
   <span class="text" itemprop="text">“The world as we have created it is a process of our 
   thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”
   </span>
   <span>by 
     **<small class="author" itemprop="author">Albert Einstein</small>**
     <a href="/author/Albert-Einstein">(about)</a>
   </span>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')

data={'quotes':[]}

for i in soup.select('div.quote'):
    
    quote = ' '.join(i.select_one('span.text').text.split())
    author = i.select_one('span>small').text

    data['quotes'].append({
        'author':author,
        'quote':quote
    })
    
print(data)
```

#### Output

```
{'quotes': [{'author': 'Albert Einstein', 'quote': '“The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”'}]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked for me and as really improve the final result.